# Why is TypeScript merging types when the code says to keep them separate?

Tags: typescript

I have [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBJA8ggvAgb2AQQAs4BbAGwC5DiSEIATAMzqMcbiilvq5cqASwDOcOgHIIAQwB2zKAGNJCAD4JJIAEa8A1gFolUOQDcQ8SQ0EJtM0SA7WbjWQuUcEFGTADmwuTo5AFcKbQsEAF9nLmibOME7B09vPwCg0PCYKOcEkkUlMCcbHj5ilxFxKRh5RQpVDUl5KDhSCysXW3tHAU7XWo9CBHs2AH4MsIi8wWmSWa7kodlmZgDfcYQQyezphISWdl6ScmpyrlL+Thcknqu+pgGlFJ9-OQ2trJzO+fmb57TAptMlNcs4CkUjtxeJcYoxKhJNC02jAGpodPojCZzJZYSQ-pDOm4Cp5lqs5OsJp95jYkRZPKxeBtxDA1l8XD9YfiCA8VmtKSDYgxotFgMYzAAKO4IAIQYII7msYRUW4PVp0ABEADoAPQUZCak5UdVRKIAGmcUDlsvlCEVypJMjVCC1uv14ONkTNwEiAEpgKKsZLnDK5fSlSrZE6XXqDZQjSbIuauJa4Naw-alo7SBqdTH3Qmk1CypoicpJObff7WME5Eo4MITAgxaYADzODAIcBwEAKUQIPQgZBQViYHAAMgQzLWpoQ7YAGp2wN3e6OANoYAC6hZIOC7PeYfYHQ5HGAXE6n5JnzgA6ovlweEABRMBKKjBZggFtYGcYAB824QAAFO99z7AADAASAgL18SJNSgjBIjAgCAEUQJXSDoLgFlyTgqDryQgCsAXPcV1PVdry3ZwABV0IfSQLlUUiHyPYcEGIhBRnYudVwY6FJA3BAghAbEAIAGTovtJHhJil1A-tBzY2iuOo3iZME4TROAX9xQYCAYCgCBRDOaU5DTAlbXDEyuEjbMgNhSIAG5cmc5MrVDCy7VuXFVTstDtW1SdSEtKhmFsdAUDQMKbjCxtSNEBs5E1BzXMYJznAuDYxKFYAfV6GAQDgYIYDkJgDKM71-Ui9AADFYG8OAW2A5i+xg388CAySEEwmC8IIAJWAiGqkM4hAaqEzYRIsf1wGgeAkFQWrw2wNsuEAmcUO0jqrhDeVnC86zfLoQCXKFVKU3MqUDos2y6H8wLRGC4JQvChaooWEBYtK+LEuS2JUvSyIgA):

```
export type IO = {
  html: {
    pdf: {
      tool: {
        list: 'pandoc' | 'ebook-convert'
        base: {
            pandoc: { margin: number }
        }
      }
      base: { margin: number }
    }
    docx: {
      tool: {
        list: 'random' | 'another'
        base: {
            pandoc: { asdf?: number }
        }
      }
      base: { padding?: number }
    }
  }
  pdf: {
    html: {
      tool: {
        base: {
            pandoc: { margin?: number }
        }
      }
      base: { margin: number }
    }
    docx: {
      tool: {
        list: 'other' | 'ebook-convert'
        base: {
            pandoc: { padding?: number }
            other: { foo?: string }
        }
      }
      base: { padding: number }
    }
  }
}

conv({
    input: { file: { path: "./my.html" } },
    output: { file: { path: "./my.docx" } },
})

conv({
    input: { file: { path: "./my.html" } },
    output: { file: { path: "./my.docx" } },
    tool: 'pandoc',
})

function conv<
    I extends keyof IO & string, 
    IX extends IO[I],
    O extends keyof IX & string, 
    W extends Exclude<O, I>,
    P extends `${string}.${I}`,
    Q extends `${string}.${W}`,
    OX extends IX[W],
    T extends 'tool' extends keyof OX ? OX['tool'] : never,
    L extends 'list' extends keyof T ? T['list'] : never,
>(
  props: {
    input: {
      file: {
        path: P
      };
    };
    output: {
      file: {
        path: Q // should be typed based on extension.
      };
    };
    tool?: L
  }
) {
  return props
}

// below here is stuff I tried playing with as well.
type Format<P extends string> = P extends `${string}.${infer F}` ? F : never

export type FileIO<
    P, Q
> = {
  input: {
    file: {
      path: P
    };
  };
  output: {
    file: {
      path: Q // should be typed based on extension.
    };
  };
}
```

The TypeScript problem is that `tool: 'pandoc'` is resolving to this:

```
(property) tool?: "ebook-convert" | "random" | "another" | "other" | undefined
```

It should resolve to this instead:

```
(property) tool?: "random" | "another" | undefined
```

If you'll notice, I am specifying on that `conv` input, `html` input, `docx` output, and the path on the `IO` type to `html/docx` shows `random | another`, not all those rest of those values. Those other values `ebook-convert | other` are coming from *the other `docx`* defined at `pdf/docx`. So for some reason TypeScript is merging the one I want `html/docx` with another one `pdf/docx`, presumably because it also has `docx` on it. Not totally sure.

How do I get it so that `tool` is scoped according to the `tool/list` type that is specific to an input and output? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The interaction between multiple `.` in your strings and `keyof` doesn't yield the expected type. For example, in the call to `conv` above, `I` has type `keyof IO` instead of `"html"`.

A shorter example of this is:

```
export type IO = {
  html: 1,
  pdf: 2
};

declare function conv<
  I extends keyof IO,
>(
  input: `${string}.${I}`,
): I;

const _1 = conv("./my.html") // type: keyof IO
const _2 = conv("/my.html") // type: "html"
```

A possible solution is to define `conv` using a helper like `Extension` as in:

```
type Extension<Path extends string> = Path extends `${string}.${infer Rest}` ? Extension<Rest> : Path

function conv<
    IX extends IO[Extension<P> & keyof IO],
    P extends string,
    Q extends string,
    OX extends IX[Extension<Q> & keyof IX],
    T extends 'tool' extends keyof OX ? OX['tool'] : never,
    L extends 'list' extends keyof T ? T['list'] : never,
>(
```

Which results in the expected error

> Type "pandoc"' is not assignable to type '"random" | "another" | undefined'

That however removes some type safety on the `path` property, which can be remedied by substituting something like:

```
    P extends Extension<P> extends keyof IO ? string : never,
    Q extends Extension<Q> extends keyof IX ? string : never,
```